# Appendix index behaves strange in header

Tags: header-footer, appendices

I need to add the appendix index into header. That's what I managed to write for it

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % кодировка исходников
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext} %Lorem ipsum

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Колонтитулы
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}          % Очистить
\rhead{\thepage}    % Добавить номер
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Без линии
\setlength{\headheight}{17pt} % Ругается, что 14 мало
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % Для страниц с заголовками раздела chapter
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\thepage}
}
\usepackage{titletoc}


\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix} % APPENDICES
\newcommand{\apx}[1]{ 
    \clearpage
    \stepcounter{chapter}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{
        \thepage (\thechapter)
    }
    \chead{
        \appendixname~\Asbuk{chapter}
    }
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{-3em}
        {#1}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\Asbuk{chapter}~---~#1}
    \par
}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter*{Введение}
    \blindtext[1]
    \chapter{Начало всего}
    \section{Начало начал}
    \subsection{Начало начала начал}
    \blindtext[1]
    \section{Продолжение начал}
    \blindtext[1]

    \begin{appendices}
    \apx{Заголовок первого приложения}
    Текст первого приложения
    \blindtext[4]
    \apx{Заголовок второго приложения}
    Текст второго приложения
    \blindtext[4]
    \apx{Заголовок третьего приложения}
    Текст третьего приложения
    \blindtext[4]
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

And that's what I get.

[image: pages]

Notice that the last chapter somewhy becomes number one instead of being the next Cyrillic letter. In ToC everything is good...

[image: ToC]

What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments.

Comment: Here is the document, sorry for russian, maybe you should pop out  the pscyr module and related things  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D5DE8C0ED293E524!7209&authkey=!AJaZE3Wde4DVpKQ&ithint=file%2c7z

Comment: No, please reduce it the minimal version that shows this issue. Most users here don't like to follow links to cloud drives etc.

Comment: OK, I will try to reproduce it in minimal environment... Not sure it will work of will be soon... Working on it

Comment: Welcome, use `\chapter` like you are supposed to do.

Comment: I prepared the document http://pastebin.com/Y2BzpdBQ

Comment: @Himura: Why again in an external link? You can add the document here to here post.

Comment: Ah, I forgot I can edit. OK, did it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `\clearpage` right before `\end{appendices}`.

Or even better, don't use the not needed `appendices` environment at all and just use `\appendix`.

[image: himuraAppendixIndex]

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % кодировка исходников
%\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext} %Lorem ipsum

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Колонтитулы
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}          % Очистить
\rhead{\thepage}    % Добавить номер
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Без линии
\setlength{\headheight}{17pt} % Ругается, что 14 мало
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % Для страниц с заголовками раздела chapter
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\thepage}
}
\usepackage{titletoc}


\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix} % APPENDICES
\newcommand{\apx}[1]{ 
    \clearpage
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{
        \thepage (\thechapter)
    }
    \chead{
        \appendixname~\Asbuk{chapter}
    }
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{-3em}
        {#1}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\Asbuk{chapter}~---~#1}
    \par
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Введение}
\blindtext[1]
\chapter{Начало всего}
\section{Начало начал}
\subsection{Начало начала начал}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Продолжение начал}
\blindtext[1]

%\begin{appendices}
\appendix
    \apx{Заголовок первого приложения}
    Текст первого приложения
    \blindtext[4]
    \apx{Заголовок второго приложения}
    Текст второго приложения
    \blindtext[4]
    \apx{Заголовок третьего приложения}
    Текст третьего приложения
    \blindtext[4]
%\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Completely unrelated, but worth a mention: 14pt font size is a bit much for a4paper.